# Dropbox VS SVN, LAN syncing

Tags: svn, bandwidth, dropbox, lan

At our new office we have a bit of a problem with file sharing. Currently we are using DropBox, but we'd prefer to use SVN because of all the extra features.

The nice thing about DropBox is, as far as I understood, that it also syncs over the LAN with other computeres, so not using the internet heavily. This is great for big art files. I don't know any SVN client that does this.

We have a rackable server here, so could use that, but it's just too noisy to run all day.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The FAQ states that questions about “software tools commonly used by programmers” are welcome. I can understand the reasoning behind the close vote, but let’s be nice.

Comment: How is this not used for software development? That is what we are doing here, you know?

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that both Dropbox and SVN will store files for you the manner in which you store them and the use cases of both systems are quite different.

Subversion is first and foremost a version/revision control tool. You do a 'checkout' to recieve all of those files stored in a central repository, if you change files you need to 'commit' those changes back to the repository for others to retrieve and others have to do an 'update' from the repository to see your changes locally and potentially 'merge' any changes you have made with their local changes. This can be quite a tricky operation to begin with and is really only suitable on plain text files. Subversion can be run entirely across your LAN.

Dropbox on the other hand is more like a file backup and sharing solution with a limited history of changes to files (1 month at the moment). Instead of merging confilcting files (i.e. files two or more users have been updating at the same time), Dropbox will save copies of the conflicting files with the name of the computer they came from appended to the file name.

Making a recommendation for one of the above or a different solution entirely cannot be based on the limited information provided. You should consider your use case, i.e. what types of files are you wanting to share? Subversion can store any type of file but where confilcts emerge, plain text is always the easier to merge.